# Is it possible to freely move the Picture in Picture window around the screen?

Tags: video, macos

Is it possible to freely move the Picture in Picture window? By default, it just snaps to the nearest corner. How can I move the window to any place I like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. Just hold down the <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> button and drag the Picture in Picture window anywhere you desire.

Comment: I was able to simply drag it, without using the command key.